# Unable to store password as Character array in Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my Objectify code  I was trying to create password field as Character Array , while saving the entity it is throwing an  Exception like "
com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException "  with a message  " password: java.lang.Character is not a supported property type ".

How do I rectify that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store passwords as String properties, but I would strongly recommend that you encrypt and salt them.